# man source code and configuration to use xz instead of gzip

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, manpage, xz

I'm wondering a few things about man pages and `man` utility.

`man` seems to be implemented as a pipeline of basic commands, such as (over-simplified):

```
zcat /path/to/man/page.3.gz | groff -man | less
```

However, there is some logic implemented:  reading `/etc/man.config`, reading the database index, browse manpath directories, etc.

## 1

So my first question is: where can I find the source code for man utility? I guess different implementations exist, so I'm mainly interested in GNU or SYSV systems (I'm using Fedora).

## 2

My second question is about compression utility and configuration. Man pages can be compressed using `gzip`. Gzipped pages are natively unzipped by `man`. However, `xz` seems to have a better compression rate than `gzip`.

Are there some `man` implementations that are compatible with `xz`? Here is an excerpt from a man page of `man` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/man):

> if the filename has a known compression suffix (like .gz), man assumes it is gzipped.

This is a bit unclear for me. From my point of view `xz` is a "known compression suffix", but it is contradictory with "man assumes it is gzipped", and I couldn't find no mention of using `xz` and `man` together.

The config file `/etc/manpath.config` allows to define for example a different pager that `less`. So I was wondering if we could define in the same fashion a different "zipper" in order to use `xz` instead of `gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

## Self-answer

### 1

Many Linux distributions (including Fedora) rely on the man-db project. Project websites here:

http://www.nongnu.org/man-db/

https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/man-db

### 2

After inspecting the source code, and testing with an official release, man-db *does* support `xz` compression.